# Bind Two Dropdown List control with database in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know the way to bind a Dropdown List control with database in VB.NET, but how can I did it if I have two Dropdown List? Both Dropdown List is from same database but what I want to populate on grid view is from Views. Can someone give me some source code to write or any advice is appreciate. Thank in advanced.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Dealer Name:"></asp:Label>
      &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Choose Dealer</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Chai</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Chang</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Aniseed</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Recipe: "></asp:Label>
      &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Choose Recipe</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Cake</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Pie</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>spaghetti</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
```

I want for example when choose DropDownList1's dealer and DropDownList2 recipe, the data grid will display the data that I stored in database(Views).

Comment: Sorry... answered too quickly. I missed the second part.

Comment: I think your goal is not clear: do you want to have two DropDownList inside two different columns of the DateGrid bound to your database? Can you post the code you wrote so far and explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: I already edited my question. Please give some advice. @Andrea